# "Видаляти" чи "вилучати" коментар?

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова

Нещодавно залишав коментар під відповіддю. Оскільки, з часом, він вже став не актуальний, я натиснув на кнопочку "delete this comment" і він пропав.

Яке слово правильно вжити у цій ситуації? Я видалив чи вилучив коментар? Чи, може, вони взаємозамінні?

У [словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyluchaty) "вилучати" означає наступне:

> Вибирати, видаляти що-небудь звідкись, із складу чогось і т. ін. На
> ряді підприємств автомати-бракувальники виявляють і вилучають
> браковані деталі (Наука і життя, 8, 1958, 19); Просушене на гарячій
> печі прядиво ми мусили довго м'яти ногами, щоб вилучити, вим'яти ту
> кляту кострицю (Василь Минко, Моя Минківка, 1962, 57);

Однак, я все одно не впевнений, який варіант краще використати у даному випадку.

Comment: Багато хто (наприклад, KDE) використовує «вилучити» як типовий переклад для «delete» (наприклад, delete file — вилучити файл). [Отут](http://linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=1055) я мало не вплутався в суперечку з цього приводу. З моєї особистої точки зору «вилучити» краще підходить, коли ми щось прибираємо, відбираємо/віднімаємо у когось, тимчасово чи назовсім виводимо зі складу чогось — а не зовсім знищуємо; в останньому випадку, на мою думку, краще підходить delete. Зі мною згодні, наприклад, Microsoft, у яких delete — видалити, а вилучити/виключити — exclude (зі списку, наприклад).

Comment: Згідно з [оцим](//english.stackexchange.com/q/52508/139407), різницю між «видалити» і «вилучити» добре передає англійська пара «delete» — «erase». «Delete» має відтінок erase, витерти, зовсім прибрати; «remove» — take away, set aside, прибрати так, що його (можливо) можна буде потім залучити назад. Дійсно, «remove» той же Microsoft часто перекладає як «вилучити» (хоча і я видалити — теж).

Comment: Тобто в цілому я вважаю неправильним перекладати *delete* як *вилучати*. *Delete* — *видаляти*, *remove* — *вилучати*. З іншого боку, оскільки і в англійській мові часто delete/remove вживаються взаємозамінно — а особливо різниця між ними несуттєва у випадку дрібного коментаря (коли втрачати то особливо нічого, пару слів), я вважаю «вилучити» — теж нормально. Але ненормально, на мою думку, «вилучити» звучить там, де мовиться про значні і безповоротні втрати інформації. «Вилучити базу даних: так/ні?» — «ну, добре, вилучімо… егей, а куди ми її вилучили, як її тепер повернути?!!»

Comment: @Artemix, хм… Ну, можу, оформити як відповідь. Але це суто суб'єктивно (хоч якісь логічні доводи і є, але…). Он я вважаю так; а KDE-шники/linux.org.ua-шники (якщо не не одна спільнота) вважають по-іншому. Хоча, так, мабуть, варто оформити; інакше обміну думок не буде; тоді можна буде і туди на форум кинути посилання сюди (а раптом зацікавляться).

Comment: Створений допис можна легко й непомітно прибрати, якщо до нього ще немає відповіді :)

Answer (score 3):

Про це йдеться у [Списку найтиповіших мовних помилок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA), див. приклади:

**Видалити зуб**, але **вилучити статтю**.

Проте, [Олександр Пономарів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/08/140811_ponomariv_blog26_ko) пише:

> **Видаляти** – це викидати, вирізувати, забирати щось звідкись. Наприклад:
>   "Загальна хірургія здебільшого видаляє уражені тканини, щоб урятувати
>   весь організм" (з журналу).
>
> **Вилучати** має такі значення: виводити зі складу, конфіскувати.
>   Наприклад: "Єпископ вилучив Ардента з церкви" (Леся Українка).
>   Вилучати овець з отари, вилучати браковані деталі, зброю.

Я так розумію, що беручи до уваги все це, то краще сказати "вилучати коментар" (однак, в другому прикладі коло слова "видаляти" бачимо значення "забирати щось звідкись" і ось тут не дуже зрозуміло чи не можна це віднести до коментаря).

Крім, згідно до Словника синонімів - ці слова не є синонімами ("[видалити](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)", "[вилучити](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)"). Однак, якщо ми глянемо які значення мають ці слова у цьому словнику, то нам не підійде ні "видаляти", ні "вилучати", а тому важко зробити якісь висновки опираючись на цю інформацію.

Зауважу, що на тій же [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) і сайті [Майкрософт](https://support.office.com/uk-ua/article/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-193dbbed-6fcf-4f07-9119-5acff81b89c5) слова "вилучення" і "видалення" вживаються як синоніми. Та й навіть сам СУМ вказує на їхню схожість у значенні "забирати щось звідкись". Тому я гадаю, що обидва варіанти можливі.

Comment: Схоже, що *видаляти* має відтінок *фізично знищувати*, а *вилучати* - *припинити належність* до якоїсь категорії. Тому, в контексті коментаря, буде більш природним сказати *видалити коментар*.

Answer (score 0):

міркували тут над перекладом "uninstall and delete"
на тепер є такий варіант "вилучити і видалити"
до того були різні поки не зупинились на схемі дія-протидія

```
install/uninstall  - залучити/вилучити
add/delete - додати/видалити
```

тобто, за цієюж логікою для коментаря мабуть буде

```
add/delete(remove) - додати/видалити
```

залучити коментар... якось дивно